# php generate a number based n last three in array - with rules

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, rules

I am trying to write what should be a short piece of code to generate a 4th number based on three. There is an array with 6 numbers in it, the code needs to take the last three (numerical order) and generate a fourth based on some rules:

if last number (array [5]) = the same as array[4] and array[5] is less than 49 then array[5] = array[5] +1

if last number (array [5]) = the same as array[4] and array[5] is equal to 49 then array[5] = array[4] -1 IF array[3] is more than 2 less than array[4]

eg:

Number 1,2,44,45,47,48

By these rules the new number can be 49, as although number number 5[4] would be the same as the generated number ([5]-1) it is less than 49 so can be number 6[5] +1 instead.

Number 1,2,44,45,46,48

By these rules the generated number can be 47, as number 5[4] is more than two away from the last number [5]

Number 1,2,44,45,48,49

By these rules the generated number would be 47, as the last number [5] is 49 and the second last [4] is the next number in reverse sequence, so cannot go higher than 49 and can't use the next number down, so uses the next number [4] -1

Essentially trickle back until the next lowest number is available if not already gone up one..

Here is what I've cobbled together - no laughing please I'm new:

```
<?php
$lunch = array("1","1","1","44","47","48");
sort($lunch);
echo '<br>';
echo $lunch[3];
echo ' - '.$lunch[4];
echo ' - '.$lunch[5];
$last = --$lunch[5];
echo '<br>Last = '.$last;
if ($last == $lunch[4]){
echo "<br>Ball 5 & pick are the same";
if ($lunch[5]<"49"){
$last = $lunch[5];
echo $last;
}

}  else {
echo "a is smaller than b";
}
?>
```

what would be the best approach? Can anybody offer some suggestions?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why are you putting numbers into an array as strings and then doing arithmetic on them!?!?!?!

Comment: Ah, the question is what would be the best approach ?

Comment: @ RiggsFolly - that is a temporary array, the actual array is auto generated and can't be as easily manipulated. It's so I can work on the code and test every scenario without having to wait for it to arise.

Comment: Then use `array(1,1,1,44,47,48);`

Comment: So what should happen if this is your array `1,2,44,47,48,49`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, normally the array is in that layout, but it still doesn't start to answer the code lol. Then the number would be 46, it trickles backwards. However I'm pretty certain I can figure that out if the other parts of the code are there as it's covered once so should be 'easy' to duplicate.

Comment: That was the point of the question, I wanted to know if you had considered that situation. Often people dont. Then when you give an answer they are all over you with "It does not work" DV DV DV.

Comment: Also the trickle back needs to be part of the question as it needs to be an intricate part of the algorithm, not an after thought

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks I'll edit it right now.